# Is there a way to export the data frame in pandas to a python objects as R does with .rda file?

Tags: python, pandas, export, dataframe

I have a data frame with 7000,000+ rows. cuz it takes about 2 hours to run the codes in order to get this data frame, I kind of want to export it so that I can import it next time without retuning the codes again.

I am just wondering besides cdv, which I personally think may not be able to handle so many records, is there another way to export the data frame as R does with .rda file?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Take a look at `to_hdf()` and `to_sql()` methods

Comment: Thx! Will that be less memory-consuming than cdv?

Comment: Once the data is in RAM as a `pandas` `dataframe`, there is no reason why memory usage should be different. But disk storage is a different story: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639877/hdf5-taking-more-space-than-csv