# Use pandas (and glob?) to merge numerous (csv) data text files from a directory

Tags: python, arrays, csv, pandas, glob

I have numerous separate instrument files of X, Y (integer) column data. All arrays are the same dimension. The X column is the same for each file, the Y column numbers are different.  If possible, I want to concatenate the Y columns of the successive files to the first file and write a new single large array containing the first X and multiple Ys? Like this:

`file1=X1 Y1 file2=X1 Y2 file3=X1 Y3...` new file result should be: `X1 Y1 Y2 Y3...`

Been looking at variations on:

```py
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('file1.csv') 
# print(data) returns the 1st file array ok
```

Need to open and loop over successive files to join Y column to file1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

def get_merged_csv(flist, **kwargs):
    return pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, **kwargs).set_index('X') for f in flist], axis=1).reset_index()

path = 'C:/Users/csvfiles'
fmask = os.path.join(path, '*mask*.csv')

df = get_merged_csv(glob.glob(fmask))
```

in order to name your `Y` columns like `Y1`, `Y2`, etc.:

```
cols = ['{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format(t) for t in zip(df.columns[1:], range(1, len(df.columns)))]
df.columns = df.columns.tolist()[:1] + cols
```

Test data:

a.csv:

```
X,Y
1,11
2,12
3,13
```

b.csv:

```
X,Y
1,21
2,22
3,23
```

c.csv:

```
X,Y
1,31
2,32
3,33
```

Test:

```
In [215]: df = get_merged_csv(glob.glob(fmask))

In [216]: df
Out[216]:
   X   Y   Y   Y
0  1  11  21  31
1  2  12  22  32
2  3  13  23  33

In [217]: cols = ['{0[0]}{0[1]}'.format(t) for t in zip(df.columns[1:], range(1, len(df.columns)))]

In [218]: cols
Out[218]: ['Y1', 'Y2', 'Y3']

In [219]: df.columns = df.columns.tolist()[:1] + cols

In [220]: df
Out[220]:
   X  Y1  Y2  Y3
0  1  11  21  31
1  2  12  22  32
2  3  13  23  33
```

Comment: Hey MaxU, this works great!!!  I used it to build a huge dataframe in seconds.  As I am fairly new to Python, do you have a recommendation on writing out the results of "df?"  Can I also pass df to MatPlotLib for plotting?

Comment: @numpystack, about writing out results - if you mean performance you may want to read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010212/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-upload-a-big-csv-file-in-notebook-to-work-with-python/37012035#37012035). In regards to Matplotlib - you would have to specify what and how do you want to plot