# Apply GZIP compression to a CSV in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, gzip

I am trying to write a dataframe to a gzipped csv in python pandas, using the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import csv
import gzip

# Get data (with previous connection and script variables)
df = pd.read_sql_query(script, conn)

# Create today's date, to append to file
todaysdatestring = str(datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d'))
print todaysdatestring

# Create csv with gzip compression
df.to_csv('foo-%s.csv.gz' % todaysdatestring,
      sep='|',
      header=True,
      index=False,
      quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
      compression='gzip',
      quotechar='"',
      doublequote=True,
      line_terminator='\n')
```

This just creates a csv called 'foo-YYYYMMDD.csv.gz', not an actual gzip archive.

I've also tried adding this:

```
#Turn to_csv statement into a variable
d = df.to_csv('foo-%s.csv.gz' % todaysdatestring,
      sep='|',
      header=True,
      index=False,
      quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
      compression='gzip',
      quotechar='"',
      doublequote=True,
      line_terminator='\n')

# Write above variable to gzip
 with gzip.open('foo-%s.csv.gz' % todaysdatestring, 'wb') as output:
   output.write(d)
```

Which fails as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Using `df.to_csv` with `compression='gzip'` produces a gzip archive for me.  I used the same keyword arguments as you.  What version of pandas as you using?  See the output of `pd.__version__` to determine this.  It looks like gzip wasn't implemented until 0.17.1, but trying to use it in earlier versions will not produce an error.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37012035/5741205) are some __tested__ examples. Actually i would recommend to switch to HDF5 - it's much faster and more convenient!

Comment: @root, that was the issue! I ran

    `easy_install --upgrade pandas`

from the command line and upgraded from 16.1 to 18.1, and the "# Create csv with gzip compression" code from the top section worked as expected. Should I edit/delete the main post to reflect this?

Comment: I'll write my comment up as an answer, and you can accept it.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Using `df.to_csv()` with the keyword argument `compression='gzip'` should produce a gzip archive. I tested it using same keyword arguments as you, and it worked.

You may need to upgrade pandas, as gzip was not implemented until version 0.17.1, but trying to use it on prior versions will not raise an error, and just produce a regular csv.  You can determine your current version of pandas by looking at the output of `pd.__version__`.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Read the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)
if you are working on a Jupyter notebook you can just type `?df.to_csv`

Comment: just want to add a documented limitation that `compression=gzip` works only when the first argument of `.to_csv()` is a file name. it won't work if it's a file object.

Comment: Note: since concatenating gunzips produces another valid gunzip, you can repeatedly do `df.to_csv(filename, compression='gzip', mode='a')` to combine dataframes into one big gunzipped file. Useful if your data doesn't fit in memory.

Comment: note that the default of `compression` is `'infer'` which means that the compression type is inferred from the file suffix, so you should be fine just appending `.gz` to your filename.

Comment: df.to_csv(filename, compression='gzip', mode='a') Trying this only for the firsttime , the csv file inside the gzip is being updated. append seems to be not working for me. Each row is read once into df when the function is called, so this action should be repeated with append functionality.

Comment: Also, `.bz2` is now also supported; faster, smaller, and widespread tooling.

Answer (score 55):

It is done very easily with pandas

```
import pandas as pd
```

**Write** a pandas dataframe to disc as gunzip compressed csv

```
df.to_csv('dfsavename.csv.gz', compression='gzip')
```

**Read** from disc

```
df = pd.read_csv('dfsavename.csv.gz', compression='gzip')
```

Answer (score 11):

From [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html)

```
import gzip
content = "Lots of content here"
with gzip.open('file.txt.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

with `pandas`

```
import gzip


content = df.to_csv(
      sep='|',
      header=True,
      index=False,
      quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
      quotechar='"',
      doublequote=True,
      line_terminator='\n')

with gzip.open('foo-%s.csv.gz' % todaysdatestring, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

The trick here being that `to_csv` outputs text if you don't pass it a filename.  Then you just redirect that text to `gzip`'s `write` method.

Comment: is this more efficient that simply passing the argument to gzip? I'm currently (as I type this) extracting about 40gb worth of tables from an old dB and decided to just loop through each table and write each iteration out with `compression='gzip'` answer but wondering if I should have used this

Answer (score 1):

```
with gzip.open('foo-%s.csv.gz' % todaysdatestring, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(df.to_csv(sep='|', index=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL))
```