# Memory Error while pickling a data frame to disk

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a 51K X 8.5K data frame with just binary (1 or 0) values.

I wrote the following code:

## Pickling the data to the disk

```
outfile=open("df_preference.p", "wb")
pickle.dump(df_preference,outfile)
outfile.close()
```

It throws me Memory Error as below:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-de66e880aacb> in <module>()
      2 
      3 outfile=open("df_preference.p", "wb")
----> 4 pickle.dump(df_preference,outfile)
      5 outfile.close()
```

I am assuming it means this data is huge and it can't be pickled? But it just has binary values.

Before this, I created this dataset from another data frame which had normal counts and lot of zeros. Used the following code:

```
df_preference=df_recommender.applymap(lambda x: np.where(x >0, 1, 0))
```

This itself took some time to create df_preference. Same size of matrix.

My concern is if it takes time to create a data frame using applymap and ii) doesn't even pickle the data frame due to memory error, then going ahead I need to do matrix factorization of this df_prefence using SVD and Alternating Least Squares. It would then be more slow? How to tackle this slow run and solve the memory error?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:**

for `1` and `0` values you can use `int8` (1-byte) dtype, which will reduce your memory usage by at least 4 times.

```
(df_recommender > 0).astype(np.int8).to_pickle('/path/to/file.pickle')
```

Here is an example with 51K x 9K data frame:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(51000, 9000)))

In [2]: df.shape
Out[2]: (51000, 9000)

In [3]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 51000 entries, 0 to 50999
Columns: 9000 entries, 0 to 8999
dtypes: int32(9000)
memory usage: 1.7 GB
```

the source DF needs 1.7 GB in memory

```
In [6]: df_preference = (df>0).astype(int)

In [7]: df_preference.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 51000 entries, 0 to 50999
Columns: 9000 entries, 0 to 8999
dtypes: int32(9000)
memory usage: 1.7 GB
```

resulting DF again needs 1.7 GB in memory

```
In [4]: df_preference = (df>0).astype(np.int8)

In [5]: df_preference.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 51000 entries, 0 to 50999
Columns: 9000 entries, 0 to 8999
dtypes: int8(9000)
memory usage: 437.7 MB
```

with `int8` dtype it takes only 438 MB

now let's save it as a Pickle file:

```
In [10]: df_preference.to_pickle('d:/temp/df_pref.pickle')
```

file size:

```
{ temp }  » ls -lh df_pref.pickle
-rw-r--r-- 1 Max None 438M May 28 09:20 df_pref.pickle
```

**OLD answer:**

try this instead:

```
(df_recommender > 0).astype(int).to_pickle('/path/to/file.pickle')
```

Explanataion:

```
In [200]: df
Out[200]:
   a  b  c
0  4  3  3
1  1  2  1
2  2  1  0
3  2  0  1
4  2  0  4

In [201]: (df>0).astype(int)
Out[201]:
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  1
2  1  1  0
3  1  0  1
4  1  0  1
```

PS you may also want to save your DF as HDF5 file instead of Pickle - see [this comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37010212/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-upload-a-big-csv-file-in-notebook-to-work-with-python/37012035#37012035) for details

Comment: quick question. This won't change the existing df data frame right? 

Second, to load the data is there similar function or do again the outfield and pickle thing?

Comment: @Baktaawar, it won't change your DF. You can use  `pd.read_pickle` for reading saved DF back - see the link with comparison for examples (which i've provided in my answer)

Comment: Ok. So your command worked. It pickled it. But it created a file of size 1.8GB. Now if I have to do matrix factorization on this data it would take time. Any suggestions to improve those?

Comment: `print(df_recommender.info())` - will show you the memory usage. Open a new question about your "matrix factorization" with sample data and desired result set - it'll help to understand what you are going to achieve.

Comment: quick question. I did as below: 

df_preference.to_pickle('df_preference.pickle'). 

It throws an error. Why is that? What if I have already created a binary matrix and don't need to do (df>0).astype(int). It doesn't seem to work without this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a memory error saving DataFrame of approximately 8.5GB to pickle. The reason was the RAM shortage. This is all for Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.7.6

Tried `df.to_pickle()` with default parameters and `df.to_hdf( ..., mode="w")`.

Both were giving me MemoryError as the process allocates additional memory when saving to these formats (HDF also apparently uses pickle internally).

I finally succeeded by saving to CSV: `pd.to_csv()`, as it does not use significant additional memory resources.

Here is the df.info() output for the DataFrame I was dealing this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Index: 141516896 entries, 1eedd4a85d23 to 1c0088d397a3
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column         Dtype  
---  ------         -----  
 0   id             object 
 1   value          float64
 2   value2         object 
 3   value3         object 
 4   value4         object 
 5   value5         object 
 6   value6         object 
dtypes: float64(1), object(6)
memory usage: 8.4+ GB
```

The resulting file is around 15Gb, but at least I have not lost my data.

Hope that helps someone.