# Python Pandas memory - subsetting and releasing main data frame

Tags: python, r, pandas, memory

I have Pandas data frame big data frame loaded into memory. 
Trying to utilize memory more efficient way.

For this purposes, i won't use this data frame after i will subset from this data frame only rows i am interested are:

```
DF = pd.read_csv("Test.csv")
DF = DF[DF['A'] == 'Y']
```

Already tried this solution but not sure if it most effective.
Is solution above is most efficient for memory usage?
Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the following trick (if you can read the whole CSV file into memory):

```
DF = pd.read_csv("Test.csv").query("A == 'Y'")
```

Alternatively, you can read your data in chunks, using [read_csv()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25962187/5741205)

But i would strongly recommend you to save your data in HDF5 Table format (you may also want to compress it) - then you could read your data conditionally, using [where](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#advanced-queries) parameter in [read_hdf()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_hdf.html) function.

For example:

```
df = pd.read_hdf('/path/to/my_storage.h5', 'my_data', where="A == 'Y'")
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37012035/5741205) you can find some examples and a comparison of usage for different storage options