# Quickly accessing/querying large delimited text file in python

Tags: python, database, numpy, pandas

After searching for a while, I have found many related questions/answers to this problem but nothing that really addresses what I am looking for.  Basically, I am implementing code in python to be able to query information from a star catalogue (in particular the tycho 2 star catalogue).

This data is stored in a largish (~0.5 gigabyte) text file where each row corresponds to an entry for a star.

A few example rows are

```
0001 00008 1| |  2.31750494|  2.23184345|  -16.3|   -9.0| 68| 73| 1.7| 1.8|1958.89|1951.94| 4|1.0|1.0|0.9|1.0|12.146|0.158|12.146|0.223|999| |         |  2.31754222|  2.23186444|1.67|1.54| 88.0|100.8| |-0.2
0001 00013 1| |  1.12558209|  2.26739400|   27.7|   -0.5|  9| 12| 1.2| 1.2|1990.76|1989.25| 8|1.0|0.8|1.0|0.7|10.488|0.038| 8.670|0.015|999|T|         |  1.12551889|  2.26739556|1.81|1.52|  9.3| 12.7| |-0.2
0001 00016 1| |  1.05686490|  1.89782870|  -25.9|  -44.4| 85| 99| 2.1| 2.4|1959.29|1945.16| 3|0.4|0.5|0.4|0.5|12.921|0.335|12.100|0.243|999| |         |  1.05692417|  1.89793306|1.81|1.54|108.5|150.2| |-0.1
0001 00017 1|P|  0.05059802|  1.77144349|   32.1|  -20.7| 21| 31| 1.6| 1.6|1989.29|1985.38| 5|1.4|0.6|1.4|0.6|11.318|0.070|10.521|0.051| 18|T|         |  0.05086583|  1.77151389|1.78|1.55| 30.0| 45.6|D|-0.2
```

The information is both delimited and fixed width.  Each column contains a different piece of information about the star.  Now, for my python utility I would like to be able to quickly search through this information and retrieve the entries for stars that match a set of criteria specified by the user.

For instance, I would like to be able to find all stars with magnitude brighter than 5.5 (col 18 or 19) that have a right ascension between 0 and 30 degrees (col 3) and a declination between -45 and -35 degrees (col 4) efficiently.  Now, if I could store all this information in memory it would be easy to read the file into a numpy structured array or pandas dataframe and retrieve the stars I want using logical indexing.  Unfortunately, the machine I am working on does not have enough memory to do this (I only ever have about 0.5 gigbytes of memory free at any given time and the rest of the program I am using takes up a good chunk of memory).

My current solution involves walking through each line of the text file, interpreting the data, and storing the entry in memory only if it matches the criteria that was specified.  The method I have to do this is

```
def getallwithcriteria(self, min_vmag=1., max_vmag=17., min_bmag=1., max_bmag=17., min_ra=0., max_ra=360.,
                       min_dc=-90., max_dc=90., min_prox=3, search_center=None, search_radius=None):
    """
    This method returns entire star records for each star that meets the specified criterion.  The defaults for each
    criteria specify the entire range of the catalogue.  Do not call this without changing the defaults as this will
    likely overflow memory and cause your system to drastically slow down or crash!

    Note that all of the keyword argument do not need to be specified.  For instance, we could run

        import tychopy as tp

        tyc = tp.Tycho('/path/to/catalogue')

        star_records = tyc.getallwithcritera(min_vmag=3,max_vmag=4)

    to return all stars that have a visual magnitude between 3 and 4.

    This method returns a numpy structured array where each element contains the complete record for a star that
    matches the criterion specified by the user.  The output array has the following dtype:

            [('starid', 'U12'),
             ('pflag', 'U1'),
             ('starBearing', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('properMotion', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('uncertainty', [('rightAscension', int), ('declination', int), ('pmRA', float), ('pmDc', float)]),
             ('meanEpoch', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('numPos', int),
             ('fitGoodness', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float), ('pmRA', float), ('pmDc', float)]),
             ('magnitude', [('BT', [('mag', float), ('err', float)]), ('VT', [('mag', float), ('err', float)])]),
             ('starProximity', int),
             ('tycho1flag', 'U1'),
             ('hipparcosNumber', 'U9'),
             ('observedPos', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('observedEpoch', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('observedError', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('solutionType', 'U1'),
             ('correlation', float)]

    see the readme of the Tycho 2 catalogue for a more formal description of each field.

    If no stars are found that match the specified input then an empty numpy array with the above dtype is returned.

    Note that both a rectangular and a circular area can be specified.  The rectangular search area is specified
    using the min_ra/dc max_ra/dc keyword arguments while the circular search area is specified using the
    search_center and search_radius keyword arguments where the search_center is a tuple, list, numpy array, or
    other array like object which contains the center right ascension in element 0 and the center declination in
    element 1.  It is not recommended to specify both the circular and rectangular search areas.  If the search
    areas do not overlap then no stars will be returned.

    :param min_vmag:  the minimum (brightest) visual magnitude to return
    :param max_vmag:  the maximum (dimmest) visual magnitude to return
    :param min_bmag:  the minimum (brightest) blue magnitude to return
    :param max_bmag:  the maximum (dimmest) blue magnitude to return
    :param min_ra:  the minimum right ascension to return
    :param max_ra:  the maximum right ascension to return
    :param min_dc:  the minimum declination to return
    :param max_dc:  the maximum declination to return
    :param min_prox:  the closest proximity to a star to return
    :param search_center: An array like object containing the center point from which to search radially for stars.
    :param search_radius: A float specifying the radial search distance to use
    :return: A numpy structure array containing the star records for stars that meet the specified criteria
    """

    # form the dtype list that genfromtxt will use to interpret the star records
    dform = [('starid', 'U12'),
             ('pflag', 'U1'),
             ('starBearing', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('properMotion', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('uncertainty', [('rightAscension', int), ('declination', int), ('pmRA', float), ('pmDc', float)]),
             ('meanEpoch', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('numPos', int),
             ('fitGoodness', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float), ('pmRA', float), ('pmDc', float)]),
             ('magnitude', [('BT', [('mag', float), ('err', float)]), ('VT', [('mag', float), ('err', float)])]),
             ('starProximity', int),
             ('tycho1flag', 'U1'),
             ('hipparcosNumber', 'U9'),
             ('observedPos', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('observedEpoch', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('observedError', [('rightAscension', float), ('declination', float)]),
             ('solutionType', 'U1'),
             ('correlation', float)]

    # initialize a list which will contain the star record strings for stars that match the input criteria
    records = []

    # loop through each record in the Tycho2 catlogue
    for record in self._catalogueFile:

        # interpret the record as simply as we can
        split_record = record.split(sep="|")

        # check that we are examining a good star, that it falls within the bearing bounds, and that it is far
        # enough away from other stars
        if ("X" not in split_record[1]) and min_ra <= float(split_record[2]) <= max_ra \
                and min_dc <= float(split_record[3]) <= max_dc and int(split_record[21]) >= min_prox:

            # perform the radial search if the user has specified a center and radius
            if search_center is None or pow(pow(float(split_record[2])-search_center[0], 2) +
                                            pow(float(split_record[3])-search_center[1], 2), 1/2.) < search_radius:

                # Check to see if we have values for both blue and visual magnitudes, and check to see if these
                # magnitudes fall within the specified magnitude bounds
                # We need to split this up like this in order to make sure that either the bmag or the vmag exist
                if bool(split_record[17].strip()) and bool(split_record[19].strip()) \
                        and min_bmag <= float(split_record[17]) <= max_bmag \
                        and min_vmag <= float(split_record[19]) <= max_vmag:

                    records.append(record+'\n')

                # if only the visual magnitude exists then check its bounds - also check if the user has specified
                # its bounds
                elif not bool(split_record[17].strip()) and bool(split_record[19].strip()) \
                        and min_vmag <= float(split_record[19]) <= max_vmag and (max_vmag != 17. or min_vmag != 1.):

                    records.append(record+'\n')

                # if only the blue magnitude exists the check its bounds - also check if the user has specified its
                # bounds
                elif not bool(split_record[19].strip()) and bool(split_record[17].strip()) \
                        and min_bmag <= float(split_record[17]) <= max_bmag and (max_bmag != 17. or min_bmag != 1.):

                    records.append(record+'\n')

                # otherwise check to see if the use has changed the defaults.  If they haven't then store the star
                elif max_bmag == 17. and max_vmag == 17. and min_bmag == 1. and min_vmag == 1.:

                    records.append(record+'\n')

    # check to see if any stars met the criteria.  If they didn't then return an empty array.  If they did then use
    # genfromtxt to interpret the string of star records
    if not bool(records):
        nprecords = np.empty((1,), dtype=dform)

        warnings.warn('No stars were found meeting your criteria.  Please try again.')
    else:
        nprecords = np.genfromtxt(BytesIO("".join(records).encode()), dtype=dform, delimiter='|', converters={
            0: lambda s: s.strip(),
            1: lambda s: s.strip(),
            22: lambda s: s.strip(),
            23: lambda s: s.strip(),
            30: lambda s: s.strip()})

        if self._includeProperMotion:
            applypropermotion(nprecords, self.newEpoch, copy=False)

    # reset the catalogue back to the beginning for future searches
    self._catalogueFile.seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)

    return nprecords
```

This is still very slow (although faster than using up all of the memory and pushing everything else into swap).  For comparison, this takes about 2-3 minutes each time I need to retrieve stars and I need to retrieve stars from this 40 or so times (with different criteria each time) in the program I am writing this for. The rest of the program takes about 5 seconds total.

My question is now, what is the best way to speed up this process (outside of getting a better computer with more memory).  I am open to any suggestions as long as they are explained well and won't take me months to implement.  I am even willing to write a function that goes through and modifies the original catalogue file into a better format (fixed width binary file sorted by a specific column) in order to speed things up.

So far I have considered memmap'ing the file but decided against it because I didn't really think it would help with what I need to do.  I have also considered creating a database from the data and then using sqlalchemy or something similar to query the data that way; however, I am not super familiar with databases and don't know if that would offer any real speed improvement.

Comment: Have you considered transforming the data file into something that lends itself to repeated queries, like an [HDF5 store](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hdf5-pytables)?  There is a small computational and harddisk storage cost to doing so the first time, but it would significantly speed up querying.

Comment: I have considered rewriting the file into something like that but not HDF5 specifically.  I will investigate it and see if it will do what I need

Comment: Is that file ASCII? Can it be chunked? Do the search queries get results from all over the file or can you expect localized results? Numpy binaries are pretty fast (np.load and np.save) to load. Assuming you can cut your data into pieces you can run each bit individually (or in threads).

Comment: Can you construct one or more indexes, mapping the most important columns onto line numbers and `seek` positions?

Comment: @armatita Yes the file is ASCII.  I had considered cutting it into chunks of ra and dec (ie split it into smaller files where each smaller file only considers a portion of sky).  If not other options turn up that may be the way I need to go.  Also, the way the file is sorted now the queries usually retrieve pieces from all over the file.  In general though most searches will focus on location so if the file where sorted in this way then the results could be chunked.

Comment: @hpaulj  I'm not sure what you mean by this.  Do basically mean have multiple files where the data is sorted by a different column or something else?

Comment: I'm thinking of an index that could be loaded into memory and used to read selected lines from the master file.  The index would not have a full record.  The index of a book is not the whole book.

Comment: Can your selection use any of the data columns, or just a subset?  Consider `usecols` as a way of loading just the data that you want to index.

Comment: @hpaulj  The index idea is interesting.  I'll have to think about that.  Generally though it would be good to have most columns available as they all contain information that may be necessary depending on the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @wflynny has already mentioned PyTables (HDF5 store) - is much more efficient compared to text/CSV/etc. files. Beside that you can read from PyTables conditionally using `.read_hdf(where='<where condition>')`.

You may want to check [this comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37012035/5741205). If your machine is UNIX or Linux you may want to check [Feather-Format](https://github.com/wesm/feather), which should be extremely fast.

Beside that i would check whether using some RDBMS (MySQL/PostgreSQL/SQLite) plus proper indexes - would speed it up. But it might be problematic if you have only 0.5 GB RAM free and want to use both Pandas and RDBMS

Comment: Storing it as an HDF5 table worked perfectly.  Access time is essentially instantaneous now (at least it is not noticeable to me whenever I make a query).  It took a while getting things into the proper format (and ended up requiring me to modify the pandas source [code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37623713/using-pandas-read-csv-with-missing-data/37624922?noredirect=1#comment62732449_37624922)) but it was definitely worth it