# Many small data table I/O for pandas?

Tags: pandas, io

I have many table (about 200K of them) each small (typically less than 1K rows and 10 columns) that I need to read as fast as possible in pandas. The use case is fairly typical: a function loads these table one at a time, computes something on them and stores the final result (not keeping the content of the table in memory).

This is done many times over and I can choose the storage format for these tables for best (speed) performance. 
What [natively supported](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html) storage format would be the quickest?

Comment: I think [hdf5](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#hdf5-pytables) is best.

Comment: Intuitively, I would agree with @jezrael. In the end it might depend on your data, so I would just try it out and benchmark it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO there are a few options in this case:

1. use HDF Store (AKA PyTable, H5) as [@jezrael has already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998594/many-small-data-table-i-o-for-pandas#comment67274829_39998594). You can decide whether you want to group some/all of your tables and store them in the same `.h5` file using different identifiers (or `keys` in Pandas terminology)
2. use new and extremely fast [Feather-Format (part of the Apache Arrow project)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/feather-format). NOTE: it's still a bit new format so its format might be changed in future which could lead to incompatibilities between different versions of feather-format module. You also can't put multiple DFs in one `feather` file, so you can't group them.
3. use a database for storing/reading tables. PS it might be slower for your use-case.

PS you may also want to check [this comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37012035/5741205) especially if you want to store your data in compressed format

Comment: Thank! Is there an advantage is combining the tables in the h5 format, given that they are not going to be used together (=in the same function scope)?

Comment: @user189035, one clear advantage is less amount of files. But if you can't group them into __small__ groups (for example: grouped by date/month/customer-id/etc.) then you shouldn't use it for bigger groups as such H5 files will grow up very fast and it's very difficult to reduce their size ...

Comment: There is one file for each location/day. I load each file to obtain a set of numbers (using an linear program). I can access them by either location or day (the computations are done independently on each file). So your advise is to group all these small files by either locations (200 of them) or days (5000) and that doing so will reduce loading times?

Comment: I would try to keep a smaller groups (10-50), but the best option would be to test it during some time (1-2 months) and to observe H5 files and their sizes...

Comment: Yes, I have no direct access to those file currently: checking the available tools;) Thanks for your views