# Inserting String at first index number pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  Index Z1  Z2  Z3 Z4
    0   0   0   A  A
    1   0   B   0  0
    2   C   0   C  0
```

I want to convert it to

```
 Index  Z1  Z2  Z3 Z4
   ABC 
    0   0   0   A  A
    1   0   B   0  0
    2   C   0   C  0
```

I want to basically insert text "ABC" before 0th index and the entire row(ABC) will not have any value
It will be okay if the index starts from 1 and not 0 as below

```
 Index  Z1  Z2  Z3 Z4
   ABC 
    1   0   0   A  A
    2   0   B   0  0
    3   C   0   C  0
```

Comment: What is `df.index.name` and `df.columns.name` ?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? While we're all keen to contribute with answers, I think this needs careful consideration. Why would you add a string to an integer index?

Comment: Main purpose is that I have many such dataframe which I am appending to  create a final csv.So inorder  to differentiate between these dataframes  in that final csv I am inserting text at the beginning of each dataframe

Comment: I just dont know why some people downvoted it

Comment: @Rookie_123, don't worry, the balance is still positive: `5+5-2-2 = +6` ;)

Comment: No I was not actually worried about that.My main concern was there should have been some concrete reason for downvoting it.

Comment: Yeah its positive :) :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need set index name or columns name. But there is possible some pandas function should remove it.

```
print (df.index.name)
None
print (df.columns.name)
Index

df.index += 1
df.index.name = 'ABC'
print (df)
Index Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4
ABC              
1      0  0  A  A
2      0  B  0  0
3      C  0  C  0
```

Better is create `MultiIndex` and select by `loc`:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['ABC'], df.index + 1])
df = df.set_index(mux)
print (df)
      Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4
ABC 1  0  0  A  A
    2  0  B  0  0
    3  C  0  C  0

print (df.loc['ABC'])
  Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4
1  0  0  A  A
2  0  B  0  0
3  C  0  C  0
```

Also if need distingush many `DataFrames` with same structure use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with parameter `keys` for `MultiIndex`:

```
#sample only, in real df1, df2, ... dfn
dfs = [df,df,df]
df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=('a','b','c'))
print (df)
    Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4
a 0  0  0  A  A
  1  0  B  0  0
  2  C  0  C  0
b 0  0  0  A  A
  1  0  B  0  0
  2  C  0  C  0
c 0  0  0  A  A
  1  0  B  0  0
  2  C  0  C  0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [53]: df.rename_axis('ABC').rename_axis('Index',1)
Out[53]:
Index Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4
ABC
0      0  0  A  A
1      0  B  0  0
2      C  0  C  0
```

index starting with `1`:

```
In [54]: df.set_index(df.index+1).rename_axis('ABC').rename_axis('Index',1)
Out[54]:
Index Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4
ABC
1      0  0  A  A
2      0  B  0  0
3      C  0  C  0
```

**UPDATE:**

> Main purpose is that I have many such dataframe which I am appending
>   to create a final csv.So inorder to differentiate between these
>   dataframes in that final csv I am inserting text at the beginning of
>   each dataframe

I would suggest to store your data in HDF5 file(s) - it has quite a few advantages compared to CSV:

- [In terms of IO operations (read/write) HDF5 is orders of magnitude faster compared to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37012035/5741205)
- it preserves original dtypes (numerical, strings, datetimes, etc.)
- it's indexes (you can store data sets that don't fit in memory and conditionally read only a needed subset)
- you can store multiple data sets (DataFrame's) in one file using different keys
- it supports compression (blosc, lzo, zlib, bzip2)

Demo:

```
df.to_hdf(r'/path/to/file.h5', 'ABC', data_columns=True)
df2.to_hdf(r'/path/to/file.h5', 'DEF', data_columns=True)
```

Comment: index starts from `1`

Comment: @jezrael, i think it's an optional step - isn't it?

Comment: Yes, is seems so

Comment: Yes I thought if that was not possible(to start index from 0) even starting index from 1 would be fine.Just for the ease of it