# Pandas - Adding dataframe with same name using to_hdf doubled file size

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, hdf5

I am newbie in Pandas module. I created dataframe and save it with name `"dirtree"` using `to_hdf`:

```
df.to_hdf("d:/datatree full.h5", "dirtree")
```

I repeated actions above. After that, when I check file size, it is doubled. I guess my second dataframe was appended to old dataframe, but checking dataframes in store and counting rows says there are no extra dataframe or rows. How could it be?

My codes to check store:

```
store = pd.HDFStore('d:/datatree.h5')
print(store)
df = pd.read_hdf('d:/datatree.h5', 'dirtree')
df.text.count() # text is one of the columns in df
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639877/hdf5-taking-more-space-than-csv), it should help.

Comment: I think this question is not related to mine, though

Comment: I'll undelete my answer when I provide more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could reproduce this issue in the following way:

Original sample DF:

```
In [147]: df
Out[147]:
          a         b           c
0  0.163757 -1.727003    0.641793
1  1.084989 -0.958833    0.552059
2 -0.419273 -1.037440    0.544212
3 -0.197904 -1.106120   -1.117606
4  0.891187  1.094537  100.000000
```

let's save it to HDFStore:

```
In [149]: df.to_hdf('c:/temp/test_dup.h5', 'x')
```

file size: `6992 bytes`

let's do it one more time:

```
In [149]: df.to_hdf('c:/temp/test_dup.h5', 'x')
```

file size: `6992 bytes` NOTE: it did NOT change

now let's open HDFStore:

```
In [150]: store = pd.HDFStore('c:/temp/test_dup.h5')

In [151]: store
Out[151]:
<class 'pandas.io.pytables.HDFStore'>
File path: c:/temp/test_dup.h5
/x            frame        (shape->[5,3])
```

file size: `6992 bytes` NOTE: it did NOT change

let's save DF to HDFStore one more time, but notice that the `store` is open:

```
In [156]: df.to_hdf('c:/temp/test_dup.h5', 'x')

In [157]: store.close()
```

file size: `12696 bytes` # BOOM !!!

**Root cause:**

when we do: `store = pd.HDFStore('c:/temp/test_dup.h5')` - it's open with the default mode `'a'` (append), so it's ready to modify the store and when you write to the same file, but not using this `store` it makes a copy in order to protect the open store...

How to avoid it:

use `mode='r'` when you open a store:

```
In [158]: df.to_hdf('c:/temp/test_dup2.h5', 'x')

In [159]: store2 = pd.HDFStore('c:/temp/test_dup2.h5', mode='r')

In [160]: df.to_hdf('c:/temp/test_dup2.h5', 'x')
...
skipped
...
ValueError: The file 'c:/temp/test_dup2.h5' is already opened, but in read-only mode.  Please close it before reopening in append mode.
```

or a better way to manage your HDF files - is to use store:

```
store = pd.HDFStore(filename)  # it's stored in the `'table'` mode per default !
store.append('key_name', df, data_columns=True)
...
store.close()  # don't forget to flush changes to disk !!!
```

Comment: This is really nuts-and-bolts explained answer, many thanks. I tried a lot to understand myself as well as size trick, I couldn't figure out why after closing store it raises an ValueError like above.

Comment: @bzimor, glad i could help :-)